# Prevent Cut Copy Paste on all textbox within Form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to prevent the functionality for a specific textbox, but following is what not being triggered for any textbox within my form:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:text').bind('cut copy paste', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Cut / Copy / Paste Disabled");
        });

    });

   </script>
```

I wrote:  ('input:text') to indicate that I want it for all textboxes.

What am i missing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8gmzgzuu/ works fine

Comment: There are easier ways to make your visitors never want to come back to your site ever again, and run away screaming "Why would someone disable copying and pasting?!!" Oh wait, maybe there aren't.

Comment: What do you want actually?

Comment: Do not break default browser behaviors and expected user interactions!

Comment: @Amit: its working there, but not on my browser(Chrome and IE)

Comment: @Aquinas: You do need them, for example Password textbox, Credit card text box etc...

Comment: @Sadiq. Nonsense. Have you ever heard of a temporary credit card number that you generate just for one transaction? I use it quite frequently. The reason is that if someone steals that number, it doesn't matter. It's not your "real" credit card number. For passwords: have you ever heard of software that stores your passwords? Of course you can't *copy* out of password fields, but that's why that's the default built in behavior.

This is 100% wrong. Trust me.

Comment: What about using `<input type="password" />` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

Comment: i have seen and we are not able to cut copy or paste items from the textbox. then what is the problem

Comment: @ Robin: As I said in the beginning: 'I know how to prevent the functionality for a specific textbox'. You are making it specific for '#textboxid'

Comment: dude do you want that cut copy and paste should not be displayed in the right menu click?

Comment: because i have checked the code and cut copy paste is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
use *on* for latest version of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').on("cut copy paste drop", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can add below attributes in the all textboxes

```
 onpaste="return false;" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" ondrag="return false" ondrop="return false" onselectstart="return false"
```

like below

```
<input type='text' onpaste="return false;" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" ondrag="return false" ondrop="return false" onselectstart="return false" />
```